# Loops in TikZ: Executing Subtraction in Math Mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

I learned today that I can execute a loop in TikZ, which makes my life a lot easier... but I'm wondering how to evaluate a numerical expression in math mode.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}

%TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
%TikZ
\begin{document}
\begin{center}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,ultra thick]
    %arrows    
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (11,0);
    %curly braces
    \foreach \x/\n in {0/35, 2/36, 4/37, 6/38, 8/39}
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] 
        (\x,-1.25) coordinate (t_k_unten) -- (\x+2,-1.25) coordinate (t_k_opt_unten);
    %vertical dotted lines    
    \foreach \x/\n in {0/35, 2/36, 4/37, 6/38, 8/39, 10/40}
    \draw [dotted] (\x, -1.25) -- (\x, -0.5); 
    %nodes
    \foreach \x/\n in {0/35, 2/36, 4/37, 6/38, 8/39}
    %%%HERE IS THE LINE OF INTEREST:
    \node at (\x+1,-1.75){$K_{35} = \n-35$};
    \draw (-1,0) node[below] {Age};
    %labels for nodes
    \foreach \x/\n in {0/35, 2/36, 4/37, 6/38, 8/39, 10/40}
    \draw (\x,0) node(\n)[below] {\n} -- (\x,0.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The code I'm particularly interested in is

```
\node at (\x+1,-1.75){$K_{35} = \n-35$};
```

Is there any way I can have the `\n-35` execute the subtraction in math mode? I.e., output should be K_35 = 0, K_35 = 1, etc... in math mode.

**Edit**: The solution I accepted created a variable outside of math mode and used the result in the node. This was fine for my purposes.

Comment: Could you say a bit more about what you want? 'Maths mode' usually means: typesetting mathematics. Do you want to calculate the result of `\n-35` and then use the result in the node?

Comment: @cfr - Yes, that is correct. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @cfr - I understand math mode to be whatever is enclosed by `$`; is this wrong?

Comment: No. At least, there are other ways of switching into maths mode, but that's one of them. In that case, I don't think you can easily have the calculation done in maths mode, no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      >=stealth,
      ultra thick,
    ]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (11,0);
    \foreach \x/\n in {0/35, 2/36, 4/37, 6/38, 8/39}
    {
      \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] (\x,-1.25) coordinate (t_k_unten) -- (\x+2,-1.25) coordinate (t_k_opt_unten);
      %%%HERE IS THE LINE OF INTEREST:
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysubtractresult}{int(\n-35)}
      \node at (\x+1,-1.75){$K_{35} = \mysubtractresult$};
    }
    \foreach \x/\n in {0/35, 2/36, 4/37, 6/38, 8/39, 10/40}
    {
      \draw [dotted] (\x, -1.25) -- (\x, -0.5);
      \draw (\x,0) node(\n)[below] {\n} -- (\x,0.5);
    }
    \draw (-1,0) node[below] {Age};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: subtraction result in node]

Comment: Very nice - now I know how to enclose multiple statements in a loop and can create a calculated variable. Thank you!

Comment: @Clarinetist But I don't do the calculation while in maths mode. I do the calculation first and then typeset the result in maths mode. Will that still work?

Comment: Yes, this will work fine

Comment: @Clarinetist OK. Great! I'm glad you clarified what you meant only *after* I'd answered, in that case ;).